# Gradle inherit dependency repo

Tags: maven, inheritance, gradle, build, build.gradle

I'm including in my current projet a library A which depends on a library B. Library A is on a repository R1 and library B is on a repository R2. Both are Maven repositories.

```
R1[ A ]
    |
    v
R2[ B ]
```

I saw that in my current build.gradle I have to declare :

```
repositories {
    maven { url "R1" }
    maven { url "R2" }
}
```

Otherwise, dependency resolution failed, saying that it can't find B.
In A's build.gradle, I've declared :

```
repositories {
    maven { url "R2" }
}
```

Am I missing something ? Is it a normal behaviour ?

Thank you communities !

Comment: I've seen this before and assumed it to be the default behavior.  The poms for `R1` likely do not contain the repository used to hold `R2`.  You might be able to solve by adding the repository blocks for `R2` in the `R1` pom

Comment: My pom.xml is generated from gradle using gradle-bintray-plugin.
Do you know how to add maven repositories in generated pom ?